# strcpy/strcat strange character output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following piece of code for a custom `String` class:

```
const String &String::operator+(const String &right)
{
   String temp;
   temp.length = length + right.length;
   temp.sPtr = new char [temp.length + 1];
   assert( sPtr != 0 );
   strcpy(temp.sPtr, sPtr);
   strcat(temp.sPtr, right.sPtr);
   return temp;
}
```

where `sPtr` is a `char*`.

But, when I execute this function on two strings, I get garbage characters as a result, like this:

```
 ]√Hâ«Ö“xË˜" = "The date is" + " August 1, 1993
```

I don't have the slightest clue what is happening. I've read a couple of testimonials of people who have gotten garbage characters before the resulting string is concatenated, but I don't understand at all why the entire string would be garbage characters.

Any help would be really great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're returning a local object by reference.  Don't do that.  Drop the & from the return type.

Comment: Thank you, other Benjamin!

It's always the small, overlooked bits that are the hardest to catch.

Comment: @Benjamin Kovach: I'm not a Behjamin, but I'll add my 2 cents anyway: now you have to make sure you are following "the rule of three". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: @BenjaminKovach I wouldn't recommend strcat/strcpy here, you are after all storing an internal length for your string, so use it when you do your memory copying, rather than relying on null termination.

Comment: Oh, p.s. I'm a third Benjamin.

Comment: @Benj This is a project for a class, and the rules are like, blatantly defined; they actually insist that we use `strcat`, but I'll keep that in mind for the future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't return an object by reference that is 'temporary'. Once the function ends the temp string is de-allocated, and since the string is set to temps address it becomes garbage.